# Which Perl module do I use to convert Pod to HTML?

Tags: html, perl, perl-pod

I need to convert Pod to HTML.  There are number of Pod::HTML and Pod::Simple::* modules.  Which one is the one I should use?

Comment: And the command `pod2html` is no use?  It contains two lines of operational code: `use Pod::Html; pod2html @ARGV;`

Comment: The HTML output for Pod::Html is not bad.  It works if you just want something quick and dirty.  But it doesn't let you set a header/footer on your html files.  Also I think its possible, but after 30 min, I still couldn't get pod to link to each other correctly.  Also Pod::Simple::XHTML just has a lot more options.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer is [Pod::Simple::XHTML](https://metacpan.org/module/Pod%3a%3aSimple%3a%3aXHTML).  It produces useful yet concise HTML output.  You can see an example of the output by viewing the html source at http://metacpan.org.

It also works with [Pod::Simple::HTMLBatch](https://metacpan.org/module/Pod%3a%3aSimple%3a%3aHTMLBatch) which you should check out if you are converting more than one file.  Note that the default for Pod::Simple::HTMLBatch is Pod::Simple::HTML.  But the maintainer of Pod::Simple, David Wheeler, [recommends](https://github.com/github/markup/pull/19) using Pod::Simple::XHTML.

```
use Pod::Simple::HTMLBatch;    
use Pod::Simple::XHTML;

mkdir './html' or die "could not create directory: $!";

my $convert = Pod::Simple::HTMLBatch->new;
$convert->html_render_class('Pod::Simple::XHTML');
$convert->add_css('http://www.perl.org/css/perl.css');
$convert->css_flurry(0);
$convert->javascript_flurry(0);
$convert->contents_file(0);    
$convert->batch_convert('./pod', './html');
```